# How to access Excel file present on SVN in automation Script

Tags: svn, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

Consider the following Scenario.

1. Automation Script created in Eclipse IDE using Maven.
2. Script uses Excel file for "test data", which is present on SVN.
3. Integrating complete Scripts with Jenkins UI

I created these scripts on my local system and was not using SVN then, as the Excel file was on my local drive, there was no problem in giving the file path in the script. But when Jenkins integration comes into Picture every thing has to be generalized and put on SVN. Thats where i'm wondering, how should i give the Path of the 'Excel File' in my Script so that it goes and finds out where exactly the file is. 
   I would be really helpful if somebody could help. Thanks in advance

I am attaching a piece of code which i had tried already.

```
 public static final String Root_Path = System.getProperty("user.dir");
 public static final String Path_Master = Root_Path+"/AutomationData/";
 public static final String File_Master = "data.xlsx";
```

where "AutomationData" is the folder on SVN in which the excel file exists and "data.xlsx" is the original excel file.

Comment: What is wrong with your code, your are doing good. Where ever you need to read excel just pass the path like this : `Path_Master\File_Master`

Comment: @Priyanshu This is my excel read code 
`InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(SORA_Constants.Path_Master+"\\"+SORA_Constants.File_Master));`

But still its not working. It wont let me use single "\" so i used "\\" instead. Since i'm not fetching my excel from local so i dont think i have to use either single or double of "\".

Comment: Why is it all in a spreadsheet?

Comment: @Arran because i want it to be in spreadsheet. Actually its the test data thats there in d excel. Well thats how it is to be implemented

Comment: @NilamberSingh What exception did you get while running it from svn?

Comment: @PriyanshuShekhar I donot get any exception at all. It just doesnt read the file contents. It should have thrown "FileNotFoundException" but i get nothing at all.. I'm using maven so i m wondering if that is the reason why i dont get exception. This is the first time i'm using maven for my project

Comment: No there is nothing bad in Maven which will stop the code to throwing exception, I'll suggest to use syso statements at different points in your code just to check where exactly it fails.